# Username in URL using Regex & Route

Tags: regex, cakephp, routes

I have a method in my Users Controller called `view`, which should display a specified (by URL) user:

```
public function view($username = null) {
    $this->User->username = $username;

    if (!$this->User->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException('Няма такъв потребител!');
    }

    if (!$username) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Няма такъв потребител!');
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    $this->set('user', $this->User->read());
}
```

And in the route config:

```
    Router::connect('/:username',   array('controller' => 'users', 'action'=> 'view'), array('username' => '^([a-z0-9])+$'));
```

But when I try: `www.example.com/Username` it returns a fatal error: Missing controller.

I tried also this:

```
Router::connect('/users/:username', array('controller' => 'users', 'action'=> 'view'), array('pass' => array('username'), 'username' => '^([a-z0-9])+$'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately for this sort of setup using `/:username` is too simple, it will pretty much override every single other route. To do this effectively ( + the proper CakePHP way) you need to setup a custom route, [here is mine which pretty much achieves the same thing](https://github.com/Dunhamzzz/Consumer-Love/blob/master/Lib/ProductRoute.php). Just replace "product" with "user" for most cases, read through it though, to make sure you understand what's going on..

Look at my routes config as well if you still can't work it out.

If you want to route **/user/dunhamzz** to a profile you would set it up like this:

```
Router::connect('/user/:username',
    array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view'),
    array('pass' => array('username')
);
```

Then your view action simply gets the username as the first argument:

```
public function view($username) {

}
```

Comment: Oh, that's just too much, I think I can live without it. Thanks anyways. Another question I have is how to achieve the following: www.example.com/user/username. I tried this: `Router::connect('/user/*',  array('controller'  => 'users', 'action'  => 'view'));` but I get the following error: `Error: The requested address '/cakephp/user/FakeHeal' was not found on this server.`

Comment: Still gettin this `Error: The requested address '/cakephp/user/FakeHeal' was not found on this server.` Also why do we pass regex?

Comment: @FakeHeal why do you have /cakephp at the front? Sounds like it's not even getting to CakePHP, do the default routes work? (/controller/action)

Comment: in *localhost* I have a folder *cakephp*. When I try controller/action - default route I get the same error: `Error: The requested address '/cakephp/users/view/fakeheal' was not found on this server.`

Comment: Then you have an issue with your environment which you need to sort out first, I can't help you with a custom route if the default doesn't work!